# Transform strings in bash - add parentheses around params

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I tried the following `sed` but couldn't quite crack how to stop on the forward slashes an apply it multiple times

```
sed 's/(.*):([^:]*)/\1{\2}/g'
```

My input looks like

```
/resource/:paramName
/resource/:paramName/another-resource
/resource/:paramName/another-resource/:anotherParam/final-resource
/resource/:aParam/another-resource/:differentParam/final-resource
```

Into:

```
/resource/{paramName}
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource/{anotherParam}/final-resource
/resource/{aParam}/another-resource/{differentParam}/final-resource
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Using GNU awk***

```
awk '{print gensub(/:([^/]*)/,"{\\1}","g")}' file
```

***Other awk***

```
awk '{gsub(/:[^/]*/,"{&}"); gsub(/{:/,"{")}1' file
```

***Sed***

```
sed  -r 's/:([^/]*)/{\1}/g' file
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat file
/resource/:paramName
/resource/:paramName/another-resource
/resource/:paramName/another-resource/:anotherParam/final-resource
/resource/:aParam/another-resource/:differentParam/final-resource
```

**GNU awk**

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/:([^/]*)/,"{\\1}","g")}' file
/resource/{paramName}
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource/{anotherParam}/final-resource
/resource/{aParam}/another-resource/{differentParam}/final-resource
```

**Other awk:**

```
$ awk '{gsub(/:[^/]*/,"{&}"); gsub(/{:/,"{")}1' file
/resource/{paramName}
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource/{anotherParam}/final-resource
/resource/{aParam}/another-resource/{differentParam}/final-resource
```

**Sed :**

```
$ sed  -r 's/:([^/]*)/{\1}/g' file 
/resource/{paramName}
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource
/resource/{paramName}/another-resource/{anotherParam}/final-resource
/resource/{aParam}/another-resource/{differentParam}/final-resource
```

Comment: looks like a complete package pal `:-)`

Comment: @sjsam these days not getting enough time to visit forum, so whenever I get time, trying to satisfy my hunger.

Comment: thank you!!! just had to escape the .* on osx and the sed one worked great! s/:\([^/]*\)/{\1}/g

Comment: I'm guessing you should properly use `[^:/]` instead of `[^/]` to completely comply with the OP's requirements.

Comment: @tripleee I still have confusion as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/nzgJuq/1) match information with `/:[^:/]`  or `/:[^/]/` doesn't make much difference, I may be wrong, if so correct me.

Comment: It doesn't appear to make any difference for the example data the OP posted, but I'm guessing there was a reason they put that in there in the first place; and, it makes your regex properly unambiguous, so it avoids unnecessary backtracking.